# R: Automatically recognizing the "type" of variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I am working with the R programming language. Suppose I have the following data:

```
#create data
var_1 = rnorm(1000,10,10)

var_2 <- c("1","0")
var_2 <- sample(var_1, 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.7))


response<- c("2", "1","0")
response <- sample(response, 1000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.3, 0.4, 0.3))

my_data = data.frame(var_1, var_2, response)

my_data$var_2 = as.factor(my_data$var_2)
my_data$response = as.factor(my_data$response)
```

I wrote the following code that makes a histogram for the "factor" variable and a density plot for the "numerical" variable:

```
  #load libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)


#first plot
p1 = ggplot(my_data) +
    geom_histogram(aes(x=var_1, fill=response), 
                   colour="grey50", alpha=0.5, position="identity")+ ggtitle("var_2 vs response")

#second plot (for some reason, this does not look correct?)

p2 = ggplot(my_data, aes(x = var_2, fill = response)) + geom_density(alpha = 0.5) + ggtitle("var_1 vs response")

grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol=2)
```

[image]

My question: Suppose I had a dataset that had many "factor" variables and "numerical" variables. Are there any functions in R that can automatically detect whether the variable is "factor" or "numerical", and then draw the corresponding graph (filled using the color of the "response variable")?

Would it have been possible to produce these graphs automatically, without manually instructing R to make the correct type of graph for each variable "type"? (e.g. suppose there were 10 variables in a dataset, would it be possible to make 10 of these graphs?)

Thanks

Comment: You could just create a function with these two chart types and then just pass it a conditional check at the beginning of a function if a certain variable is of type factor or of type numeric (e.g. with`is.factor(x)` or `class(x)` or other means and then simply put an if else condition before your plots that says "if numeric then do histogram, otherwise do density plot". Oh and of course, if you want to automatically apply to a bunch of variables, then you might want to put everthing into a for loop that goes through your data column by column.

Comment: In an `if`-statement, you can use e.g. `is.numeric`, `is.factor` and `is.character` (such that you know that you have a character which needs to be converted to a factor in your case)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with `lapply` -

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

var_cols <- grep('var', names(my_data), value = TRUE)

do.call(grid.arrange, c(lapply(var_cols, function(x) {
  if(is.numeric(my_data[[x]])) {
    ggplot(my_data) +
      geom_histogram(aes(x=.data[[x]], fill=response), 
                     colour="grey50", alpha=0.5, position="identity") + 
      ggtitle(paste(x, 'vs response'))
  }
  else {
    ggplot(my_data, aes(x = .data[[x]], fill = response)) + 
      geom_density(alpha = 0.5) + 
      ggtitle(paste(x, 'vs response'))
  }
}), ncol = length(var_cols)))
```

[image]

Comment: this is perfect, thank you! The system tells me I need to wait 5 minutes before I can "accept" your answer

Comment: Do you know why the density graphs are looking "uneven"?

Comment: Hmm..I am not sure about that.

Comment: I fixed the problem with the histogram: ggplot(my_data) + 
    geom_bar(aes(x = var_2, fill = factor(response)), position = position_dodge(preserve = 'single'))

Answer (score 1):

We may try this solution:

1. Convert to a tibble
2. `type.convert(as.is = TRUE)` to get the most realistic type
3. Convert all integers to factors across all columns

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gridExtra)

my_data1 <- my_data %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.integer), factor))



#first plot
p1 = ggplot(my_data1) +
  geom_histogram(aes(x=var_1, fill=response), 
                 colour="grey50", alpha=0.5, position="identity")+ ggtitle("var_2 vs response")

#second plot (for some reason, this does not look correct?)

p2 = ggplot(my_data1, aes(x = var_2, fill = response)) + geom_density(alpha = 0.5) + ggtitle("var_1 vs response")

grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol=2)
```

[image]